# I am using a carousel to show images but cant fix image to cover background using an unordered list

Tags: css, position, html-lists, background-image

I have managed to create a carousel for images using html5, css3 and Jquery. Unfortunately I can not figure out the simple task of getting the images to fill the background entirely. They rotate but are all different sizes. I have changed it so much that I have got in a muddle, can anyone help?

**CSS**

```
.wrapper {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 0;
    padding-top: 0px;
}

.slider {

    overflow: hidden;
}

.slider li {

    margin: 0 auto;
    list-style: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-repeat: none; 
}
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<title>Gallery</title>
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
<script src="js/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div class="wrapper">
<ul class="slider">
  <li><img src="after_front.jpg"/></li>
  <li><img src="after_scenicView.jpg"/></li>
  <li><img src="after_lib.jpg"/></li>
  <li><img src="after_mac.jpg"/></li>
  <li><img src="after_gym.jpg"/></li>
  <li><img src="after_lounge.jpg"/></li>
</ul>
</div>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js">  <\/script>')</script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Any advice would be appreciated! Complete novice here. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things that might be the issue. The first may be that your `li` is not filling the area of the `.slider` list. You can add `height: 100%` and `width: 100%` to the list items see if that fixes the issue. The other problem might be that your browser doesn't support `background-size: cover`. If that is the case you can try the proprietary browser tags for it:

```
.slider li {
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    background-size:100% 100%;      
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader
        (src='image/path/name.png',sizingMethod='scale');
}
```

If that doesn't fix the issue, you can always go the route of putting the images in the HTML as DOM elements. You can then just write your CSS to say `'width: 100%' and they will always fill the parent width. This does lead to some issues with centering the image, but it will get the job done!

**Based on your HTML update**

The problem is that the property `background-size: cover` only works if you define the image using the `background-image: url(../path/to/file.jpg)`. Since the images are DOM elements, they are not considered backgrounds, rather they are just block level elements. You could either rewrite your CSS to handle HTML images or you can change your HTML to this:

```
<ul class="slider">
    <li style="background-image: url('after_front.jpg');"></li>
    <li style="background-image: url('after_scenicView.jpg');"></li>
    <li style="background-image: url('after_lib.jpg');"></li>
    <li style="background-image: url('after_mac.jpg');"></li>
    <li style="background-image: url('after_gym.jpg');"></li>
    <li style="background-image: url('after_lounge.jpg');"></li>
</ul>
```

The paths to your images might not be right, so you should check to make sure that you aren't getting 404 errors on them. Also, since they are not DOM elements anymore, you will have to define a height in your CSS.

Comment: I seem to still have the same problem, it does not want to recognise the background -size! Thank you for trying :)

Comment: It might not be covered by your [browser](http://caniuse.com/#feat=background-img-opts). If that is the case you can use a [polyfill](http://nooshu.com/jquery-plug-in-scalable-background-image) that will fix the issue.

Comment: I am using Chrome, safari and IE11 if it doesn't work on them then its useless?

Comment: Weird! It might be that you are targeting the wrong element either with the CSS or the HTML. Can you confirm that the `li` is the element with the `background-image` attribute?

Comment: yes it is, i will add to my question my html code for you to see. I have changed the codes and now the images are too big and i need to adjust the zoom on the browser!